# Is there already a git command for executing a script "in" a given branch?

Tags: git

I want to avoid reinventing the wheel. I'm thinking of a tool that helps me in development:

I want to compare the performance impact of some refactoring / tuning, where I have the original code in one git branch and the refactored and tuned code in another branch.

Then I have a small script that runs the relevant code and records some timings.

Ideally I'd like to be able to say something like

`git run_cmd_for_ref original_branch -- python benchmark_script.py`

`git run_cmd_for_ref other_branch -- python benchmark_script.py`

I can see writing a simple custom git command shell script to do that task but thought I'd ask about it first. I tried an internet search, but all the search results merely talk about running commands in git bash (for windows users) or about comparing branches via `git diff`.

Comment: What do you mean by "in a given branch"? I assume you mean that the code of that commit is checked out? So, wouldn't that be `git checkout branch && python my_script.py`?

Comment: Haha. Of course it would be. I have been way overthinking this.

Comment: Maybe? You could also utilise work-trees, but that might be more trouble than it's worth